# Separate taskbar button for dialog

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, taskbar

I am supporting a WinAPI/ATL based app with many dialog windows created depending on user actions. Most of the dialogs are unowned windows. If several dialogs are created at the same time, their taskbar buttons are grouped together on the Taskbar (default behavior).

Now I have a task to create a separate taskbar button for one of dialog windows. I can't find any relevant info on how to do this.  I even tried to use the `ITaskbarList` COM interface, but its `AddTab()` method works like the default model above.

Is it possible to place more than one button on the Taskbar for one instance of the app? If yes, please explain how I can implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows 7 and later, you can assign a different [Application User Model ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459.aspx) to the dialog and it will not be grouped with the other dialogs on the Taskbar.

See Raymond Chen's blog article about this topic:

[How do I customize how my application windows are grouped in the Taskbar?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120820-00/?p=6813)

Also see:

[Developing for the Windows 7 Taskbar — Application ID](http://www.sevenforums.com/news/13684-developing-windows-7-taskbar-application-id.html)

For example:

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE hinstPrev,
                   LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(L"MyCompany.MyApp.MainProcess");

    ...

    HWND hDlg = ...
    IPropertyStore *pps = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(hDlg, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pps))))
    {
        PROPVARIANT pv;
        PropVariantInit(&pv);
        InitPropVariantFromString(L"MyCompany.MyApp.LoneDialog", &pv);
        pps->SetValue(PKEY_AppUserModel_ID, pv);
        PropVariantClear(&pv);
        pps->Release();
    }

    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for an answer, SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID() solved my issue :)

Comment: In fact I have seen these links before, but was hoping that exists more easy way for single-process apps, because by current solution I need to recover previous AUMID after the target dialog window was shown
(sorry for my English)

Comment: @Vitaliy you would only have to restore a previous AUMID if you are planning on having the dialog display its own Taskbar button and then later remerge into the main group. Remember, each window can have its own AUMID, `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID` just sets a process-wide default AUMID, but each window is not restricted to that AUMID.